# Change color of a TextView on press with selector not working

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to achieve a color change from brown to green when user presses and holds the `TextView` area.

My Selector code (located in `res/color` folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/main_menu_text_battle_mode_on"/>
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/main_menu_text_battle_mode_on" />
        <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/main_menu_text_battle_mode_on" />
        <item android:color="@color/main_menu_text_brown"/>
</selector>
```

My `TextView` al. `TypeWriter` in `LinearLayout`:

```
<model.TypeWriter
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/endAllBattles"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="End all battles"
        android:textColor="@color/main_menu_text_color_selector"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />
```

Colors `styles.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="main_menu_text_brown">#653823</color>
    <color name="main_menu_text_battle_mode_on">#005500</color>
</resources>
```

Project folder structure:

[image]

The color is always brown. Any idea? I was first thinking it could be incorrect folder structure, but brown color works.

Build `Build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'ParseCrashReporting-*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'gson-2.3.1.jar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

            }
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                        'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-new.pro'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For what I can see the pressed state of your text is never selected because you have `android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false"`. Try deleting `android:state_enabled="false"` from that line or change it's value to `true`

Comment: Tried that already, doesn't work ;/

Comment: Is TypeWriter a class that extends TextView?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it does.

Comment: I just did a quick version that works for me: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/green" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/green" />
    <item android:color="#FFF" />
</selector>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Use only these

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/main_menu_text_brown" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/main_menu_text_battle_mode_on" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/main_menu_text_brown" />
</selector>
```

Comment: remove "android:duplicateParentState" from textView It will work fine